# How to integrate a Jsp file to ColdFusion?

Tags: jsp, coldfusion

I have created a web page using ColdFusion. In that cfm file I have the following tag for 
redirection:

```
<a href="pingdirect.jsp?Directory=#insdirs.ID_Directory#&Qlid=#inc_Requestor#">Grant
```

This is my `Pingdirect.jsp` file:

```
String param=request.getParameter("Directory");                   
String qid=request.getParameter("Qlid");           
try {
    String command1="Runas /user:"+param+" /grant "+qid+":(OI)(CI)(M,RX,W)\"";
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p=rt.exec("cmd /c start" +command1);
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

My problem is that when I click "grant", it redirects the page to `pingdirect.jsp`.
But it does not open the command prompt.

Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but your code is taking input from a user and executing it without validating the input. If I request Pingdirect.jsp?Directory=administrator%40del%20c:\ then bad things could happen

Comment: That directory and qid values will be taken from the database. Thats are all rest of my coding part.. Here i have just shown the redirection line only..

Comment: Where are you expecting to see the CMD prompt?

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by looking at the parameters that are trying to be passed through...

Remembering in jsp there can appear to be no difference between GET and POST variables where as in ColdFusion these exist in the URL and FORM scope respectively.

Where do insdirs.ID_Directory and inc_Requestor come from and is it possible that they are being not set or set incorrectly.

If you manually navigate to the pingdirect.jsp?Directory=[expected value]&Qlid=[expected value] page what happens (and what values are needed in the query string (the url parameters)?

I'd suggest that you keep variable names that are passed by query all in one case (so make Directory directory and Qlid qlid).

If you can manually get there and the parameters are being passed through correctly it's probably time to start debugging the jsp page line by line.

Ben

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I extract some columns from database using cfquery. I stored that values in to variables (Directory and qid). Then i passed this using a href. When i execute cfm file it redirects the page to pingdirect.jsp and picks the values correctly.But it is not executing the below two statements.                             Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();                                Process p=rt.exec("cmd /c start" +command1);                           Please clarify this as soon as possible..

Comment: Does the jsp behave "correctly" when you run it manually by literally typing into the address bar the url for it?
I'm afraid my jsp is very rusty, but as barnyr says earlier if this does work it looks like a rather large security hole.

Comment: ya The jsp file works fine.I tried to redirect this jsp page from a sample html file.(Server :Apache Tomcat and IDE:Eclipse)                                             a href=pingdirect.jsp?Directory=.....&qid=...                            For this i'm getting the command prompt and it passes that Parameters correctly.. But when i redirect it from coldfusion to jsp file i didn't get the command prompt...                                          Thanks

Comment: In which case I'd try in the ColdFusion file hard coding the correct values directly above the link that you have above and confirm that that works.

Comment: yes Benny The values are fetched to url and to param and qid Variables correctly from coldfusion (see my .jsp file above). Then i add these string variables with command1. Upto this its fine. Then i pass that command1 variable with rt.exec(). Here i dint get the command prompt. This is my problem.  (If i give a href="http://localhost:8090/Testproj/pingdirect.jsp?Directory=..&qid=.. It works and it displays the command prompt)..        Thanks-

Comment: Sorry perhaps I'm not being clear:
If this works correctly when you add the variables manually in the ColdFusion document then it has to be that the variables are being set incorrectly in the ColdFusion document.

Somewhere else to look is is the line in the ColdFusion document within cfoutput tags?  To test this, if it's not clear in the document, try right clicking on the link and copying and pasting it to a text editor to confirm that the correct link is being created.

Comment: @user1484609 - Re: *Here i dint get the command prompt* 1) What does happen? Are you getting an exception - if so, can you post it? 2) Dump the values of `param` and `qid` on your jsp page, what are the values? 3) Lastly, this may be a stupid question but are you are using `<cfoutput>` tags around your hyperlink so the variables are evaluated properly?

Comment: Oops, I did not notice BennyB mentioned #3 already. But it is a good thing to check.

Comment: As others have said, if it works ok when hand-typing the URL but not via the CF-generated link, then the link is likely different. If the difference isn't apparent, try running Fiddler (fiddler2.com) and use that to capture the two requests and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing getParameter with getAttribute;

```
String param=request.getAttribute("Directory");                   
String qid=request.getAttribute("Qlid");
```

and, additionally, verify that the attributes actually exist;

```
if ((param == null) || (qid == null)) 
{
// MZ: Handle the exception here
}
```